# Launch a bundle file with apple script

Tags: applescript

I have a bundle file on osx with a .stack extension. eg test.stack.
Normally a user will double click this file, and that launches a helper app "StackInstaller" momenterally, that copies the .stack file to another pre-determined folder(same folder every time).

I would like to script this with apple script if possible. But i aint big on apple script and my first attempts are failing.

eg:

tell application "Finder" open file "test.stack" of [pathtomydesktophere]

another attempt :

tell application "StackInstaller" open file "test.stack" of [pathtomydesktophere]

Really i want to simulate a user double clicking the .stack file, and i wrongly assumed thats what the open command was doing.

Kind regards Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a shell script: `open ~/Desktop/test.stack`

Comment: Brilliant i got that to work. If anyone using livecode see's this the format is :    put "open" && specialFolderPath("desktop") & "/goodteststack.stack" into tTest
   get shell(tTest)